# Is this a bug in Matlab function call?

Tags: matlab, function, debugging, call

The code I am using here is for illustration of the possible bug. In the code I defined three functions as below and tried to visualize them.

The first:

```
$$y_1(x)=5\sin(x)$$
```

The second:

```
$$y_2(x)=12-8\cos(x)$$
```

The 3rd is a piecewise combination of the above two:

```
when x<0:
$$y_3(x)=y_1(x)$$

when x>=0:

$$y_3(x)=(y_1(x)+y_2(x))/2$$
```

When I run the following code in Matlab, which is saved as `m2mPlot.m` :

```
function m2mPlot
clear all
close all
clc

global a b c;
a=12;
b=8;
c=5;
t=-pi:.1:pi;

plot(t,y1(t),'b')
hold on
plot(t,y2(t),'m')
plot(t,y3(t),'r')
legend('y1','y2','y3')


function y=y1(t)
% The first function for testing
global c;
y=c*sin(t);

function y=y2(t)
% The 2nd function for testing
global a b;
y=a-b*cos(t);

function y=y3(t)
% The 3rd function for testing
if t<0  % It seems this logic value is always FALSE, why?
    y=y1(t);
else
    y=(y2(t)+y1(t))/2;
end
```

I got:

[image]
which indicates that in the third sub-function the logic expression: t<0 is always FALSE no matter what value t actually is.

Is this a bug in Matlab? How to avoid such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug in MATLAB, you're just using it incorrectly.

You are calling `y3(t)` where `t` is a vector, i.e. `t=-pi:.1:pi;`. But the code for `y3` uses `t` in a conditional, i.e. `if t<0`. Since the result of `t<0` is a vector, and the `if` statement expects a scalar, it will not work as you expect. As Troy Haskin points out in the comments, from the MATLAB [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html#description):

> if expression, statements, end evaluates an expression, and executes a group of statements when the expression is true. An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). 
>   Otherwise, the expression is false.

Your `t<0` vector contains many `false` values and so the `if` evaluates it as `false`. I would advise you to simply only ever give a MATLAB `if` a scalar.

If you want to create your `y3` function in a vectorized manner try this instead:

```
function y=y3(t)
    y=y1(t).*(t<0) + y2(t).*(t>=0);
end
```

Comment: You are correct on the [`if` behavior](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html#description): "An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false."

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the slight difference when the input argument is not a scalar.